# Terminal mysql -v gives Access Denied Error 1045 (28000)

Tags: terminal, osx-mountain-lion, mysql-error-1045

When I try to check the mysql version using terminal I get the following error.

```
KillBill:~ KillBill$ mysql -v
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'KillBill'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

but when I do the following and add the password it works and logs me into MYSQL prompt.

```
KillBill:~ KillBill$ mysql -u root -p
```

Why am I getting the following error on mysql -v prompt only. What do I do to fix it? Everything else is working fine, I can connect to mysql db in the apps I am developing no problem whatsoever.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Q: Did you grant permissions to user 'KillBill'@'localhost' in MySQL?  `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name TO user@host IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start the mysql client without givinng the -u option, it assumes you want to login with the current username, in your case KillBill. If this user isn't a mysql user or is a mysql user, but has to specify a password to login, the user will be refused a connection.

Login as "root", create a mysql user names "KillBill" and assign a password. Have look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html) for the syntax of that. Then assign appropriate rights using the GRANT statement.